# Is there a terser way to bind a method to an object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, syntactic-sugar

I often find myself using the pattern

```
object.methodname.bind(object,...)
```

to bind a method to its owning object for when I need to pass a function into another function.

Does Javascript have a terser way to do this?

Comment: You could write your own helper function `bind(object, "methodname")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ES5, what you've written is the most succinct way of binding an object's method to itself.

There is a proposal for ES2016 (né ES7) for a new [this-binding syntax](https://github.com/zenparsing/es-function-bind)

```
Promise.resolve(123).then(::console.log);

$(".some-link").on("click", ::view.reset);
```

The unary form `::foo` is shorthand for `foo.bind(foo)`, while the binary form `bar::foo` is shorthand for `foo.bind(bar)`

While ES2016 does not yet exist in a finalized form, you can use this syntax today via a [Babel plugin](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-function-bind/), either by itself or as part of [preset stage 0](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-0/).

Answer (score 0):

You should use prototypes:

in some ways it is similar to classes in c++/Java/#c

```
function Person(name, phone){ //constructor
    this.name = name;
    this.phone = phone;
}
Person.prototype.someMethod = function(){
    return this.name + ' ' + this.phone;
}
```

and creating an instance of `Person` is done just like this:

```
var john = new Person('John', '123456789');
console.log(john.someMethod());
```

Comment: That doesn't address the issue at hand at all. The question is about passing a function into another function and binding that function to its owning object when the passed function is a method.